# "Searched on" vs "searched about"

Tags: word-choice

When to use the former and when to use the latter?

Example:

> I went to the Internet and searched everything I could **on** animal
>   behavior.
>
> I went to the Internet and searched everything I could **about** animal
>   behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ...

> search **on** some subject

and...also

> search **about** something/one

What looked somewhat strange is *"you **went to** the internet!'*

Do you mean that you *went to the cyber cafe?*

Internet is not a physical shop here, so 'went to' **in this context** does not sound proper to me. Even if it's used, I'd go for a better option.

Common use is..

> I searched everything about/on animal behavior on the Internet that I could.

Comment: There are many "I went to the Internet" on Google Books, though: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22I+went+to+the+internet+and%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=BddJVeWSDcTKmwWhvYGoBA&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1221&bih=809

Comment: 'Searched on the internet' is way more common than 'went to the internet'. My personal suggestion is don't use "I went to the Internet". It really looks strange!

Comment: People certainly do say "I went to the internet and searched for everything I could think of related to animal behavior", but it's a colloquialism.  Some people even say things like "I asked the internet about animal behavior".  I guess personification is a step beyond figuratively referring to the internet as a location :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't use *every* this way. *Every* is an adjective, not a noun or pronoun.

> I went to the Internet and searched *everything* I could **about/on** animal behavior.

I don't think there is much difference here, although I would say *about* is more precise.

If you look for "regarding" or "concerning" in the definitions of "about" and "on" you should be able to understand the relationship.

Comment: This seems pretty much right. I think you're missing a 'for' before 'everything'.

Comment: Yeah, adding *for* would go a long way to fix this answer.  It would also help not to say that *every* is an adjective, since it's usually a determiner.